# Valide AWS Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

After a succesful connection to Facebook through AWS Cognito, the client is receiving this:

```
{
   "AccessKey": <hash>,
   "Expiration": <datetime>,
   "SecretKey": <hash>,
   "SessionKey": <hash>
}
```

How do I validate, on a remote REST API, that those credentials are valid?
There is no Credentials.validate() in any SDK.
It seems that I need to use this credential object and use it against pretty much any AWS Service.
What would be the best option here?
Note: my backend API is written in Golang

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to validate the credentials themselves. If any credentials that you send to AWS are invalid, AWS will respond with a 403 error and refuse to process your request.

However, if you need to check if the current user has the required **permissions** to perform a certain AWS API call, [the `DryRun` parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) can help you here:

> Checks whether you have the required permissions for the action, without actually making the request. If you have the required permissions, the request returns DryRunOperation; otherwise, it returns UnauthorizedOperation.

Comment: Those credentials are provided by a simple user, from his mobile App, to my API. I need to do a quick check and make sure it has not been impersonated.Good point for the dry run thanks a lot!

Comment: How does a check to "make sure it has not been impersonated" help?  What does that accomplish?